# Access Redirect Url from Azure B2C Policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure B2C Tenant that is being used by multiple single page applications (spa app) for authentication. Each spa has their own redirect URL that is being set in the URL while the spa calls the b2c URL. I am looking for a way to access the redirect URL being sent in the B2C URL in the b2c policy, so that I can log the value using an external service call from b2c policy. Is there a way to get the value of the redirect URL from b2c policy itself, may be from some technical profile?

Since the redirect URL is being sent in the query parameters, it must be getting stored somewhere on the b2c server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the OpenID Connect parameters, including Redirect URI using [Claims Resolvers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#openid-connect).

You can use claims resolvers as an input claim or output claim in a technical profile such as the API call to an external service call or [Application Insights Technical Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/analytics-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

Comment: Thanks, Worked like a Charm!